# Как выполнить вставку по условию? Ошибка: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

Нашёл [здесь](http://psoug.org/snippet/INSERT-WHEN_588.htm), что синтаксис выглядит следующим образом: <sub>(прим.ред. источник больше не доступен)</sub>

```
INSERT
WHEN ([Condition]) THEN
INTO [TableName] ([ColumnName])
VALUES ([VALUES])
ELSE
INTO [TableName] ([ColumnName])
VALUES ([VALUES])
SELECT [ColumnName] FROM [TableName];
```

Но использовать значения из другой таблицы не требуется, а надо просто ввести новые заначения, поэтому делаю так:

```
INSERT 
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FOO WHERE NAME = 'JOE') 
THEN
INTO BAR (NAME, AGE) 
VALUES ('JOE', 50)
```

но это приводит к исключению:

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword.

Как выполнить вставку с новыми значениями, если заданное значение найдено в другой таблице?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to insert conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41849762) от участника [@Kamil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873995/kamil)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/41849762

Answer (score 4):

Причина ошибки  в том, что вставка по условию [см. conditional_insert_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__I2121821) является частью мульти-табличной вставки [см. multi_table_insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__I2121682). Последняя синтаксически требует в конце обязательный подзапрос. Неважно, будут ли значения, полученные из этого подзапроса, использованы для вставки или нет. Так же неважно, что вставка производится только в одну таблицу. Важно однако, сколько строк вернёт подзапрос.

То есть для одиночной вставки подзапрос должен вернуть ровно одну строку:

```
create table t1 (id, val) as
    select 1, 10 from dual;

create table t2 (id, val) as
    select 2, 20 from dual;

insert
when exists (select 1 from t2 where val = 20) 
then into t1 (id, val) values (3, 30)
select null from dual;

1 row inserted.
```

Если таблица для вставки одна, то проще:

```
insert into t1 (id, val) 
select 4, 40 from t2 where val = 20 fetch first 1 row only;

1 row inserted.

select * from t1;

         ID         VAL
----------- -----------
          1          10
          3          30
          4          40
```